# How to set screen-orientation for other apps?

Tags: android, screen-orientation

With the following lines we can set the orientation with in the application..

setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

If I want to set the orientation to every screen(not only with in application). how can i do this? Any help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think it's not possible... at least not easily and you would probably need a rooted phone.

Comment: Maybe by editing the prefs of the phone (don't forget to get the good rights into the manifest).

Comment: If you mean every "screen" even outside of your own application, then I certainly hope you *can't* do that. Inside of your own application you already have one way listed, and you can also set the orientation for each Activity in the manifest.

Comment: Agreeing with the gentleman above me.  Your app is sandboxed and will have no control over other applications unless you make an app for rooted devices.

Comment: It is posible, in the notification drawer of the Galaxy Tab there is a lock orientation option. Im not sure how they did it though. Perhaps you can find the source for the build of android used on the galaxy tabs and locate it in there.

Comment: I use Smart App Protector on an unrooted phone and it can control orientation of any app. I'm not sure if this is related though.

Answer (score 0):

```
 setRequestedOrientation(0);
       or
 setRequestedOrientation(1);
```

horizontal (landscape) - 0 
vertical (potrait) - 1

You can try this.

Or you can try it in your way.
 In the onCreate method of that activity, which orientation you like to change,put this code in that. It will change that layout orientation.